# google play services, resultcode 0 onactivityresult

Tags: android-studio, oauth, google-play-services, leaderboard

I've been trying to connect up to google play services without any success. I've been checking that all the keys and id's are correct.

But I'm not getting any traffic on my API manager.
What on earth could be the problem?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(TAG, getSHA1CertFingerprint(this));
    Log.d(TAG, getAppIdFromResource(this));

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();

    textUpdate();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "requestcode " + requestCode + " resultcode " + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this, requestCode, resultCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(Highscore.this,StartScreen.class));
}



public void btnGoogleHigh (View view){
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(mGoogleApiClient),
                RC_UNUSED);
    } else {
        BaseGameUtils.makeSimpleDialog(this, getString(R.string.leaderboards_not_available)).show();
    }
}

public void btnLogin (View view){
    mSignInClicked = true;
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
public void btnLogOut (View view){
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected(): connected to Google APIs");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended(): attempting to connect");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed(): attempting to resolve");
    if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed(): already resolving");
        return;
    }

    if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
        mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;
        if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this, mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        }
    }
}

private boolean isSignedIn() {
    return (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart(): connecting");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop(): disconnecting");
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

static String getAppIdFromResource(Context ctx) {
    try {
        Resources res = ctx.getResources();
        String pkgName = ctx.getPackageName();
        int res_id = res.getIdentifier("app_id", "string", pkgName);
        return res.getString(res_id);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "??? (failed to retrieve APP ID)";
    }
}

static String getSHA1CertFingerprint(Context ctx) {
    try {
        Signature[] sigs = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
        if (sigs.length == 0) {
            return "ERROR: NO SIGNATURE.";
        } else if (sigs.length > 1) {
            return "ERROR: MULTIPLE SIGNATURES";
        }
        byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(sigs[0].toByteArray());
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; ++i) {
            if (i > 0) {
                hexString.append(":");
            }
            byteToString(hexString, digest[i]);
        }
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "(ERROR: package not found)";
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "(ERROR: SHA1 algorithm not found)";
    }
}
static void byteToString(StringBuilder sb, byte b) {
    int unsigned_byte = b < 0 ? b + 256 : b;
    int hi = unsigned_byte / 16;
    int lo = unsigned_byte % 16;
    sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".substring(hi, hi + 1));
    sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".substring(lo, lo + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the documents about "[Troubleshooting Issues in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting)" and "[Debugging Your Android Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/logging)". This documents will help you debug and resolve the issue encountered in your game.

> If you are unable to sign players into your game, first make sure that you have followed the instructions to create your client IDs and configure the games services. If you still encounter sign-in errors, check the following items to make sure that your game is set up correctly.
>
> - Check your metadata tags
> - Check your package name
> - Check the certificate fingerprint
> - Check that test accounts are enabled

For code implementation purposes, kindly check the [samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/) by Google. This will show you the basic login, multiplayer, cloud saving and more.

Hope this helps.